# Apache: create a virtual directory from .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to access files from a folder in my server from my webroot. However, the folder exists outside of my webroot. For example, I want to access `/mystuffs/myphoto.png` as in `http://mysite/mystuffs/myphoto.png`.

I have to do this through .htaccess. I can not edit the http.conf or add an symlink. Is it possible to do it this way? If yes how?

Comment: Do you mean .htaccess in the mystuffs folder?  Or can you put/edit htaccess in the docroot?

Comment: .htaccess should be in the docroot. yes

Comment: I'll expand into an answer in about an hour.